# Content Aware Caching for Commerce Related Views

Tags: commerce, caching

[Views Content Cache](https://drupal.org/project/views_content_cache) Project Page reads

> This module implements a views cache plugin that is aware of content
>   and can provide caching for views, until the content in those views
>   changes.

Do we have an equivalent for `Drupal Commerce`. So that when I have a view listing of Commerce Orders or Products, I can provide caching until the content(orders or products) in those views changes.

Answer (score 1):

The list of products uses Views, so in theory the module should work for views in admin/structure/views/view/commerce_products